# Mongo filter documents by array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have to filter candidate documents by an array of objects.

In the documents I have the following fields:

```
skills = [
  { _id: 'blablabla', skill: 'Angular', level: 3 },
  { _id: 'blablabla', skill: 'React', level: 2 },
  { _id: 'blablabla', skill: 'Vue', level: 4 },
];
```

When I make the request I get other array of skills, for example:

```
skills = [
  { skill: 'React', level: 2 },
];
```

So I need to build a query to get the documents that contains this skill and a greater or equal level.

I try doing the following:

```
const conditions = {
  $elemMatch: {
    skill: { $in: skills.map(item => item.skill) },
    level: { $gte: { $in: skills.map(item => item.level) } }
  }
};

Candidate.find(conditions)...
```

The first one seems like works but the second one doesn't work.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many problems with this query...

First of all `item.tech` - it had to be `item.skill`.

Next, $gte ... $in makes very little sense. $gte means `>=`, greater or equal than something. If you compare numbers, the "something" must be a number. Like 3 >= 5 resolves to `false`, and 3 >= 1 resolves to `true`. 3 >= [1,2,3,4,5] makes no sense since it resolves to `true` to the first 3 elements, and to `false` to the last 2.

Finally, $elemMatch doesn't work this way. It tests each element of the array for all conditions to match. What you was trying to write was like : find a document where skills array has a subdocument with skill matching at least one of [array of skills] and level is greater than ... something. Even if the $gte condition was correct, the combination of $elementMatch and $in inside doesen't do any better than regular $in:

```
{
    skill: { $in: skills.map(item => item.tech) },
    level: { $gte: ??? }
}
```

If you want to find candidates with tech skills of particular level or higher, it should be $or condition for each skill-level pair:

```
const conditions = {$or: 
    skills.map(s=>(
        {skill: { $elemMatch: {
            skill:s.skill, 
            level:{ $gte:s.level }
        } } }
    ))
};
```